# android using ffmpeg add custom image as a frame

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg for making and editing videos. I've successfully converted array of images to videos. Now i want to add custom images as a frame to whole video. I've searched a lot but couldn't find the exact solution.
I've used drawbox tool of FFmpeg but with it we can only make colored frames. I want to add custom image as a frame.

This the frame that i want to add to whole video

[image: X]

Comment: Do wou want to insert new a frame or replace an existing one?

Comment: my video has no frame because i made it using array of images..So, i want to add new frame to whole video..

Comment: so like an overlay image to the whole video?  There is a filter for that I believe, either that or manually add it somehow to each image before inserting it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using FFMPEG for Android(Kotlin). So you need to add Frame for your entire video. That can be done by using below command.

```
val complexCommand = arrayOf("-i", videoPath, "-i", "/sdcard/frame.jpg" , "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:x=600:y=600", destPath)
```

**videoPath** = existing video path (video is created using array of images and saved to sdcard)

**/sdcard/frame.jpg** = path to your frame image

**destPath** = where you want too save video after frame added.

Let me know if you still facing issue.

Note: You can use same command for Java.

Comment: Using you solution the overlay image is added to center bottom of the video..
I actually want to set the width and height of image exactly same as the width and height to video..

Comment: I'm not getting any command to set the size of overlay image..if you know then kindly help me with this..

Comment: @ZohaibIslam See the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter. Many examples are on this site.

Comment: @llogan i've used this command to overlay frame image on the video but it's not giving proper overlay..
    'scale2ref[b][a];[a][b]overlay'

Comment: @ZohaibIslam I can't give you a command that you can copy and paste without seeing the actual command you tried. You're relying on the default input order: refer to the scale2ref documentation and tell scale2ref which input is the reference and which is the frame (or be lazy and switch input order).

Comment: @ZohaibIslam Please go through [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), you will find all commands with documentation.